# How do I connect a three phase transformer with three center taps?

Tags: transformer, power-electronics, three-phase, power-engineering

I have a three phase step down transformer with three center taps like shown below:

[image]

How can I connect it to get the 90 V three phase lines or the 45 V three phase lines at a time for circuits that don't require a neutral?

Comment: You simply only half the winding or you only use the full winding. Do you know about wye and delta? Just do that with all the half windings or all the full windings, depending on what you choose. Make sure the phasing is correct though.

Comment: So you mean just simply connect all the 0's together in the secondary winding ?

Comment: Yes I am aware of Y-Delta connections

Comment: @Shamooooot "connect all the 0's together?" Only if you want a wye connection. If you need a delta connection you'll connect the 0 V tap of one winding to the 90 V or 45 V tap of the next winding in sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the full VA capacity, I believe that you need to connect delta - delta as shown below. You need to pay close attention to start of winding.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The transformer could be effectively utilised in a three-phase DC power supply (full wave rectified using centre-tapped secondaries).

[image]

The average output voltage would be a little over 60 V DC with a 3 x 380 V AC input (delta connected).

Comment: Thank you vu2nan, so I can't utilize the 90v secondary's like shown in the example ?
I am looking to achieve something like the below module:

https://www.leybold-shop.com/technology/technology-equipment/power-electronics-and-drive-technology/controlled-static-converter-circuits/line-commutated-static-converter-circuits/fault-simulator-phase-control/transformer-45-90-3-n-72680.html

Comment: Hi Shamooooot,  Of course you can, as suggested by Charles Cowie, to obtain 3 x 90 V ~ or 3 x 45 V ~. You can also reproduce the Leybold module for experimental purpose. The only difference would be to connect the primaries in delta.